# Why is the indicator function of rational numbers a simple function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, simple-functions

I understand the simple function is one that is measurable and takes on finitely many values. However, the amount of values in the set Q are infinite. Thanks

Comment: The indicator function, any indicator function, takes on at most two values.

Comment: The indicator function of the rationals is $f\colon \mathbb R \to \{0,1\}$ with $f(x)=1$ iff $x\in \mathbb Q$. It only takes two values.

Comment: Is it because it only takes on the value 0 and 1?

Comment: Ah I see, very stupid, thanks!

Comment: Yes!  Well, you also have to argue that $\mathbb Q$ is measurable, but as it is countable it has measure $0$.

Comment: thanks @lulu for the help